# Nancy on Linux is using 100% CPU

Tags: linux, mono, docker, nancy

My nancy web-apps are using up together 100% CPU without them actually being used.

They are running inside a docker container on mono. The only thing I could think about to cause this, would be the endless loop in my main function, something like

```
while(Console.ReadLine() != "quit") {}
```

but I thought, `Console.ReadLine()` would be blocking and therefore this loop would only execute, whenever there is some input, which there shouldn't be ever. Amy I missing something? Are there other reasons for nancy to use up all the CPU in mono? - In Windows during development it seems to run fine.

**Update:**

The application in docker is simply started with `mono NancyServer.exe`. The memory usage is much lower than the previous XPS-base version (50-70MB instead of 160-180MB), but the XPS-based application uses less than 0.1% of CPU (also not really doing anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the non-blocking behaviour by starting a container in the foreground if none of the [`-t` or `-i` options](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#foreground) are used. In that particular case then `Console.ReadLine()` won't block.

If either `-i` or `-t` is used, then `Console.ReadLine` blocks. Also if I run the container in the background (with the [`-d` option](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#detached-d)), `Console.ReadLine()` is blocking.

---

Make sure to use either `-t` or `-i` if you run your container in the foreground.

Comment: It's running in the background, I'll  check the exact parameters and come back to you

Comment: out of all the flags (`-i`, `-t`, `-d`) I am only setting `-d` And you said, with `-d` `Console.ReadLine()` was blocking for you, or? Did you build the container on top of the `mono` image?

Comment: I built an image on top on the `mono` image and merging your `while` loop into [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) example + `CMD sh -c "mcs hello.cs && mono hello.exe"`

Comment: Ok thats weird, as I'm also using the mono image, the only thing I'm doing differently, my application gets compiled on Visual Studio Online and I create the image from the compiled code (which got compiled in windows with the .net framework). Since I don't need to stop the application with input text, I changed the loop to `while (true) { Thread.Sleep(Int32.MaxValue); }` which works for me for now, but thx very much for trying all the different possibilities

Comment: You can remove the while loop and simply `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);` instead

Answer (score 1):

The high CPU load is caused by that while loop because you don't put the current thread to *sleep* for a short time. Like:

```
while(Console.ReadLine() != "quit") {Thread.Sleep(10);}
```

Comment: but shouldn't `Console.ReadLine` block and wait until I type something in? - which should never happen. I've now changed it to sleep for `Int32.MaxValue` (roughly 23 days) - let's see if that really was the problem